# Why the mysql query time on my computer is ten times that of others

Tags: mysql, sql

Why the mysql query time on my computer is ten times that of others. Although it is the same SQL, it is just a simple count statement, which is executed in `less than one second` on other people's computer, but I need `12 seconds`.

And we are on the same network, there is no difference in computer performance, I tried MySQL workbench, phpMyAdmin and other GUI, all take more than ten seconds.

**I really don't know why?**

[image]

I did a lot of tests and found that this is not related to my computer. Most likely related to GUI tools.

The following is all the tests I did：

```
| GUI Tool         | OS                        | Query Time |
|------------------|---------------------------|:----------:|
| MySQL Workbench  | My Ubuntu 18.04           |    ~12s    |
| PyCharm Database | My Ubuntu 18.04           |    ~13s    |
| Datazenit        | My Ubuntu 18.04           |    ~12s    |
| Sqlectron        | My Ubuntu 18.04           |    ~1s *   |
| phpMyAdmin Web   | My Ubuntu 18.04           |    ~12s    |
| Adminer Web      | My Ubuntu 18.04           |    ~1s *   |
| MySQL Workbench  | Colleague1 Windows 10     |    ~12s    |
| HeidiSQL         | Colleague1 Windows 10     |    ~1s *   |
| PyCharm Database | Colleague2 Ubuntu 18.04   |    ~13s    |
| HeidiSQL         | Colleague3 Windows 10     |    ~1s *   |
| Sequel Pro       | Colleague4 Mac OS X       |    ~1s *   |
| SQL CLI          | MySQL server host         |    ~1s *   |
```

**Why these tools (Sqlectron, Adminer, HeidiSQL, Sequel Pro) are much faster than others?**
Or why others are much slower, and how to fix it?

Comment: Show us the same picture from a computer that runs the query quickly?

Comment: Colleagues are off work, provide more information tomorrow